# How do achieve this comparison in STL priority_queue inside C++ Class

Tags: c++, templates, object, stl

*This is NOT a duplicate question It differs here as the comparison function has a dependancy on the main class.*

All my logic is in a class. I have a map `nodeCnt` which can be looked up upon `getCnt()` . I am figuring out for how to have a custom comparison `myCmp` for my priority queue `pq` which will do comparison based on the map.

The following snippet does not work. And having `auto cmp` as described in [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) cannot be done as Class cannot have such declarations for comparison function.

```
Class AllLogic {

 private:
   std::map<int, int> nodeCnt;

   // This is my confusing part
   std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(&myCmp)> pq(&myCmp);

 public:

   int getCnt(int val) {
     if (nodeCnt.find(val) != nodeCnt.end())
         return nodeCnt[val];  
      return 0;
    }

  bool myCmp(int left, int right) {
     return getCnt(left) < getCnt(right);
  } 
};
```

Comment: Hi @kfsone. This is not duplicate. This is 'slightly' different from existing ones.

Comment: The comparison function has a dependancy on the main class. Unlike the related duplicate link you have posted.

Comment: Don't say "does not work" here on stackoverflow, but just describe the problem...

Comment: `myCmp` is a member function so its use would require an instance off of which to call it, `this` is not implied. To remedy this, use `function` and a lambda: `priority_queue<..., std::function<bool(int,int)> pq([this](int a,int b){return this->myCmp(a,b);});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a struct like this:

```
// forward declare your class, because the comparator will use it
class AllLogic;

struct MyCompareT
{
    AllLogic* object;
    bool operator()(int left, int right) const;
};

// after AllLogic has been defined
bool MyCompareT::operator()(int left, int right) const {
    return object->myCmp(left, right);
}
```

And your `priority_queue` can be defined as:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, MyCompareT> pq;
```

And initialized in the constructor like this:

```
AllLogic() :pq(MyCompareT{this}) {}
```

Comment: I like the way your comparison functor reuses the comparison of the class. DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You can rework the code a bit to the following (note: the following is c++11):

```
#include <map>
#include <queue>
```

The comparison functor takes a reference to the map, and uses it to compare:

```
struct myCmp {
    explicit myCmp(std::map<int, int> &nodeCnt) : nodeCnt_{&nodeCnt} {}

    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const {
        auto lhs_it = nodeCnt_->find(lhs);
        auto rhs_it = nodeCnt_->find(rhs);
        auto lhs_val = lhs_it == nodeCnt_->end()? 0: lhs_it->second;
        auto rhs_val = rhs_it == nodeCnt_->end()? 0: rhs_it->second;
        return lhs_val < rhs_val; 
    }

private:
   std::map<int, int> *nodeCnt_;
};
```

The class sets the map, then the comparison functor, then the queue; each one uses the previous one:

```
class AllLogic {
private:
   std::map<int, int> nodeCnt;
   myCmp myCmp_{nodeCnt};
   std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, myCmp> pq{myCmp_};
};

int main(){}
```

Comment: Can u add little comment on how the operator() works? I notice that nodeCnt_ is a copy of nodeCnt. But how are updates to nodeCnt getting reflected in nodeCnt_

Comment: @visweshn92 It takes it by reference, and stores it by pointer. So any changes to the original object, are automatically present here too. It's actually *not* a copy.